# How to Access XLabel in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid Chart to draw a BarChart.

I want to Underline the Xlabel of the Bar which is selected by User. I need a way to access the label at a given index.

Any thoughts on whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BarChart barChart = ...;
XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
```

Instead of `Barchart` you can use object of any other chart type too.

Alternatively, via `BarData` object:

```
List<String> xValues = barChart.getBarData().getXVals();
```

Then access the index:

```
String valueAtIndex1 = xValues.get(1);
```

Comment: @Philipp Can I access xLabel at a given Index specifically. i.e. say my xLabel string array is ["A","B","C","D"]. Now chart is rendered and after that user selects the bar correspnding to "C". I want to access "C" and underline it just to represent that user has selected that bar.

Comment: Of course, the code I posted returns a list. See updated answer.

Comment: what about line chart? LineData does not have such a method , getXVals()